# how to select data which have same maximum value

Tags: mysql

How to select data from table which have column role(integer),name(varchar).
I need to get all data which same name with max role.

Answer (score 2):

Getting maximum Role from tableName

```
SELECT MAX(ROLE) FROM TABLENAME
```

Getting All rows/values for table with Max(ROLE)

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE ROLE= (SELECT MAX(ROLE) FROM TABLENAME)
```

Comment: Without the subquery, you would use the `HAVING` construct: `select foo_Column from tbl having max(role)`.

Comment: @hd1 Although there are no of ways to perform the asked task. thanks for your feedback.. i have mentioned the easier ones.

Comment: sorry, i have little change